# React app didn't render correctly when I deployed it to github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I try to deploy my react app to github pages, but it seems that it didn't work properly. I got a blank page when I tried to visit it by link. Anybody knows solutions? Thank you for your help!

My code is like:
`package.json`

```
  "homepage": "https://yunxiuqiu1115.github.io/food-ordering-site",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

I ran `npm run deploy` and get the successful outcome.

Everything works well locally, but does not work in github pages. Hope that anyone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to install GitHub Pages package as a **dev-dependency**.

```
cd **
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

Add properties to package.json file.

Follow this for more details https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f

Comment: Yep I did that but I got the blank page. I only put a `<div>` in my `index.html` and rendered everything in it but it didn't work in github pages

Comment: Can I know your node version?

Comment: As you mentioned above, it works locally, but if it does not work on the Github pages, it may have a dependency version mismatch.

Comment: Hi I just solved the problem. Actually I add online "main":"index.js" and I fixed the problem lol